# Display user information based on who is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to display user information based on who is logged in. I read somewhere that it's possible if you use "session" but i'm not too clued up on that. This is my current code and I want it to show information relating to that user and not the whole table.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as picture. Edit the question and add your (formatted) code into there.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the WHERE  clause. That is ->

```
    SELECT * from employees WHERE user_email="input_email";
```

This should work.

Comment: And you really should edit your question; remove the picture and type the code directly. It's hardly visible